# Constant Binormal Implies Curve is Planar (Frenet-Serret)

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

Using the standard Frenet-Serret notations (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas)

We have a claim:
If $\gamma(s)$ is a normalized curve in $R^3$ and $B(s) = b_{0} \in R^3$ then $\gamma(s)$ is a planar curve, that is, it is contained within a plane.

The proof in my book follows as such:

Since $B(s)$ is constant, and $N(s) ,T(s)$ $\bot$ $B(s)$ it follows that $N(s) ,T(s)$ span a plane perpendicular to $b_{0}$, call it $P$.

(*)They go on to say that there exists a point, $s_{0}$, such that $\gamma(s_{0}) \in P$.

Further

(**) since $T(s) \in P$ for all $s$ then $\int T(s) \in P$, for all $s$.

and conclude: $\gamma(s) = \gamma(s_{0}) + \int\limits_{s_{0}}^s T(s) \in P$

I'm having a hard time understanding the starred lines;

(*) may follow since if that weren't true, the curve would be spanned by $B(s)$ and thus $N(s)$ must equal zero, but $||N(s)|| = 1$ necessarily.

Can you explain (*) and (**) please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is actually incorrect, so it's a good thing you have problems understanding it. $N(s)$ and $T(s)$ span a plane $P_0$ *through the origin*, and we must consider the plane $P$ *parallel* to $P_0$ and passing through $\gamma(s_0)$. If $T(s)\in P_0$ for all $s$, then indeed it's true that $\int_{s_0}^s T(u)\,du\in P_0$ for all $s$. However, you might be happier to show that $\gamma(s)\in P$ for all $s$ a different way: Say $A$ is a normal vector to $P_0$ (hence to $P$). This means the plane $P$ is given by $A\cdot x = A\cdot\gamma(s_0)$. Differentiating $A\cdot\gamma(s)$, we get $0$ (why?), and so $A\cdot\gamma(s)=A\cdot\gamma(s_0)$ for all $s$, which is to say that $\gamma(s)\in P$ for all $s$.

Comment: Hey Ted, thanks for your answer, I have some questions:
1. you're saying we can't guarantee (*) and thus we're choosing some parallel plane that contains a point on the curve?
2. can you please explain why $T(s) \in P_{0}$ for all $s$ implies $\int T(u) \in P_{0}$?
Thanks,

Comment: Because $A\cdot T(u)=0$ for all $u$ (and $A$ a constant vector) tells us that $$A\cdot \int_{s_0}^s T(u)\,du = \int_{s_0}^s (A\cdot T(u))\,du = 0.$$ And yes to 1. :)